# Android - Viewpager, Adapter getItem null object

Tags: android, android-fragments

Parent activity:

```
public class FriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnListChanged {

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myCustomTabAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
 @Override
    public void onListChanged()
    {
  MyFragment fragment = (FriendsFragment) tabAdapter.getItem(flag-1);

         fragment.OnEventEditedAction(5, 5); // called
}
}
```

MyCustomTabAdapter:

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
   return MyFragment.NewInstance(position + 1);
}
```

MyFragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnEventEdited{

private OnListChanged onListChanged;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout _swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public void OnEventEditedAction(int flag, int action)
    {
**_swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);** // null here
    }

@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try
        {
            onListChanged = (FriendsActivity) context;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
        }
    }
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Setting swipeRefresh
        _swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        _swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
            }
        });
}
```

I have a button in my fragment then when I click the button I call the interface like this.

```
onListChanged.EventListChanged();
```

Then the event get called in My parent Activity:

```
public void onFriendListChanged()
```

And this event call the event in my fragment but this swiperefresh is null

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(boolean)'
>   on a null object reference

I have a tab of 4 fragments, the fragments are the same "MyFragment" but with different list. When the list in viewpager(3) changed I need to notify viewpager(1) and update the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues, the fragment my not be attached to the activity yet when `onListChanged()` is called or the `getItem()` method does not return the actual fragment so you need to instantiate it.

Override `onAttachFragment()` in your activity and call the interface method from there:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    ((FriendsFragment) tabAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem())).OnEventEditedAction(5, 5);
}
```

Instead of `viewPager.getCurrentItems()` you can pass you desired index.

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment lifecycle onViewCreated() will be called after onAttach(). So there is a chance to _swipeRefreshLayout to be null.

Return onListChanged after _swipeRefreshLayout's initialization.

Put your code in following sequence with Fragment Lifecycle. Below order should be followed. Put it in same lifecycle method call, else put it in sequence order.

```
    _swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
    _swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
        }
    });
    try
    {
        onListChanged = (FriendsActivity) context;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
    }
```